# Simple SQL result zero rows

Tags: sql, select

I have really simple SQL which howevere returns 0 rows:

SQL:

```
SELECT `article_id`, `article_title`, `article_url`, `article_text`, 
article_img`, `article_shares`, `article_likes`, `article_date`, 
(SELECT COUNT(comment_id) FROM ci_comments WHERE comment_aid=article_id) 
AS commentCount
FROM (`ci_articles`)
WHERE `article_url` =  'Jednym-slovom2'
```

SQL Table:
[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I would look for hidden characters inteh data like tabs or carriage returns. Those can make seemingly simple queries return unexpected results.

Comment: try to check you query like WHERE `article_url` like '%Jednym-slovom2%', does it return some rows?

Comment: @HLGEM - How can I check the hidden characters?
RomanPekar - it returns 0 rows as well

Comment: Edit - the LIKE query returns 1 row

Comment: I var_dumped the variable which is inserted into database and the result is: string 'Jednym-slovom2' (length=15), I think there can be some \n or something like this

Comment: I solved it with trim function. It worked after all thansk for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Is your column `article_url` a padded column?  If it always has 15 characters, then you might have whitespace at the end of the data that is less than 15 characters, ie 'Jednym-slovom2' might actually be 'Jednym-slovom2 '.  The MS Sql Server datatype NCHAR will have columns like this. To solve this problem, just use text wildcards on your search like '%Jednym-slovom2%'

Comment: The datatype is VARCHAR(255) and it is not always 15chars

Answer (score 1):

Try to copy the text out of the table and into your where clause.  That will pull out spaces and weird characters.

Comment: I tried but the result is still 0 rows. I used trim function to the variable which is being post into that column and also var_dumped it and I get -> string 'Jednym-slovom2' (length=15)

Comment: Jednym-slovom2 is 14 characters.  There must be a fifteenth character you can't see.

Comment: Ye I used trim and now it's okay